# Default valarray passing doesn't work

Tags: c++, std, default-arguments, valarray

In C++, I have two functions:

```
do_work(args, std::valarray<double> arr=std::valarray<double>(0.0, 1)) {
  very_complicated_things
}

wrapper(args, std::valarray<double> arr=std::valarray<double>(0.0, 1)) {
  do_work(args, arr);
}
```

Calling do_work(args) and calling wrapper(args) gives different results.  The former works fine; the latter crashes somewhere in the do_work function and I have no idea why (the code is quite complicated).  Why is this the case?  If I omit the "arr" argument in the function call inside wrapper:

```
wrapper(args, std::valarray<double> arr=std::valarray<double>(0.0, 1)) {
  do_work(args);
}
```

then wrapper(args) works fine!  Does anyone have an idea what's happening?  I don't know where to start looking.

Comment: Well, the heap will be in a slightly different state between the two cases.

Comment: Off topic, you should use 1. or 1.0 as 1 is integer, not double. Some compilers will give annoying warnings about it.